OkHttp version error when integrating SDK (.aar file) into my React Native project
I am trying to integrate an SDK that uses OkHttp (version 3.x.x) into my React Native (OkHttp version 4.x.x) project.
implementation files('libs/android_sdk.aar')

During integration I get an error "Duplicate class okhttp...". I fixed it with:
configurations.all {
    exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    exclude group:'com.squareup.okio', module:'okio'
}

However, after integrating the SDK, the Axios requests in my app no longer work. I get an error:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method cookieToString(Lokhttp3/Cookie;Z)Ljava/lang/String; in class Lokhttp3/internal/Internal; or its super classes

I understand that this error is due to mixed versions of OkHttp.
Is there any way to encapsulate libraries of SDK so that they do not affect my project?

Does this answer your question? How to implement okhttp 5.0.0 in react native module

@BobSmith no. Version rollback from 4.x.x to 3.x.x of OkHttp inside React Native could help me. But it's not that easy.
